# How do I layout view sizing/position programmatically in the viewController and handle rotation smoothly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm creating my view hierarchy programmatically in `loadView` in my ViewController. I have to manually calculate the subview's layout since autoresizing won't work for my layout (I've tried a lot). I have tried putting the layout code in a helper method that gets called from the VC's `viewDidRotateFromInterfaceOrientation...` and that works, but its obvious that the view rotated and then everything snapped into place. From what I'm seeing I should override the `layoutSubviews` method and it will animated at the same time its rotating? But since `layoutSubviews`is a `UIView` method not a `UIViewController` method I would have to expose all my subviews to the view so I could identify them and set the layout. What am I missing here?

I also thought if I set the size during `- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` that would work, but since the ViewController's view doesn't have its frame adjusted yet for the rotation  it doesn't layout properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making a `UIView` subclass and laying out all subcontrol locations in this. This way I just override the `layoutSubviews` method and everything works. I guess this is really what Apple intended but it seems that most code I've seen only overrides `UIView` when they need custom drawing, not for basic control placement.

Answer (score 0):

I think, yes, override willRotateToInterfaceOrientation. Correct, the view's bounds' is not updated yet, but you can probably calculate it yourself without too much trouble. Then start an animation to the new positions/sizes with the same duration as passed in the parameter.

Comment: While its not hard to calculate the new frame in theory (just swapped width/height) when you throw in things like `UINavigationBar` or `UIToolBar` and they change heights depending on orientation it gets more complicated. It would seem bad form to hard code the different bar sizes, and I don't know of any way to query the bars to determine what size they will become.

Comment: You can probably assume their heights will stay the same, and their widths will be full width.

Comment: Still that seems like the wrong way to do it. Just assuming elements will change size to a hard coded size seems bad. Is there no way to read the values that the view and its subviews's frames will animate to in the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method?

Comment: It doesn't have to be hard-coded. For example pseudo-code: `new_height = window_width - (window_height - old_height)`. Anyway whatever gets the job done. If you worry about everything that "might" break ...